# How to get Subscription ARN from Amazon SNS in order to unsubscribe from it

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm using Amazon SNS and Cognito to subscribe and unsubscribe from topics certain devices.

*Note that there may be a similar topic, but Amazon no longer use that clases.

So far, so good...

But in order to unsubscribe a device from a topic, I need to pass the Subscription ARN which I'm unable to figure out within the App.

The Subscription ARN is made by the topic ARN (that I know) and an alphanumeric string that is generated by Amazon (that I don't know).

This code:

```
AWSSNSUnsubscribeInput *input = [[AWSSNSUnsubscribeInput alloc] init];
input.subscriptionArn = @"arn:aws:sns:XXXXXXXX-YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY-ZZZZZZZZZZZZZ";

NSLog(@"Input subscription: %@", input.subscriptionArn);

[sns unsubscribe: input completionHandler:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
    if (error) {
        NSLog(@"Error occurred: [%ld]", error.code);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Success");
    }
}];
```

It works fine if I get the Subscription ARN from the AWS console, but down in the App I have no possible way of querying or generate that field.

I guess there's a walk-around, but so far I was unable to get any successful approach. How should I proceed to get this done?

Thank you all very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unsubscribe an iOS Device from an amazon SNS topic?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22196478/how-to-unsubscribe-an-ios-device-from-an-amazon-sns-topic)

Comment: No, I already read this thread. Amazon no longer use those classes.

Comment: Root problem may be the same, but the implementation is different and there's no clear solution achieved anyways.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the topic ARN call `[sns listSubscriptionsByTopic: input]`.  The response will have a list of all the subscriptions for that topic, including the subscription ARN.  You'll have to use the `owner` property on the response to find the specific subscription to pass to `unsubscribe`.

Comment: looks expensive if you consider that some topics could have a large amount of subscribers no?

Answer (score 0):

Something that I finally came with:

The "ListSubscriptions" or "ListSubscriptionsByTopic" API operations should return the subscription ARN:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_ListSubscriptions.html
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sns/latest/api/API_ListSubscriptionsByTopic.html